# How do I send an EmailMessage with multiple views (html and plain text) using EWS 2.0 API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I would like to send an email using Exchange Web Services 2.0 API that contains multi-parts of HTML and Plain Text. I understand that the HTML component gets converted to plain text for clients that can receive plain text only, but I would like the flexibility of adding *completely* different content to the plain text portion of the email. Here's what I have tried to implement:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(exchangeService);
emailMessage.ToRecipients.Add(toAddress);
emailMessage.From = fromAddress;
emailMessage.Subject = subject;
emailMessage.Body = htmlBody;
emailMessage.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;
emailMessage.TextBody.Text = textBody;
emailMessage.TextBody.BodyType = BodyType.Text;
```

EmailMessage.TextBody is read only and therefore cannot be assigned a value. 
Setting TextBody.Text throws this exception which I cannot resolve:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.
  Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
  Name=TextBody
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag.get_Item(PropertyDefinition propertyDefinition)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.get_TextBody()
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at the outlook api instead of EWS ?

Comment: @EasyE, I am creating the emails server-side, therefore I need to use EWS to create and send the emails. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok I understand, is you email account which is sending that email a 365account ?

Comment: @EasyE  Ok so we are using a self hosted exchange (2013) but for backward compatibility reasons, we set the exchangeVersion to 2007_SP1. I require these multi-part emails to be able to send from Exchange or Office365 accounts.